# aiohttp client closes session too early on ^C

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp V2.0.7 with Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 having troubles with nested blocks in code like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            with contextlib.closing(MyServerSession(loop, session)) as ss:
                # this was simplified for testing!
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(job1(ss), job2(ss))
    except aiohttp.ClientError as ce:
        log.error("HTTP session lost, retrying", client_error=ce)
        time.sleep(10)
```

MyServerSession() implements close() to log out on the server, but hitting ^C yields:

```
future: <Task finished coro=<MyServerSession.logout() done, defined at my_server.py:134> exception=RuntimeError('Session is closed',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "my_server.py", line 75, in _do_REST
    async with self.session.request(verb, self.url + '/' + resource, timeout=timeout, **kwargs) as resp:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 626, in __aenter__
    self._resp = yield from self._coro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 164, in _request
    raise RuntimeError('Session is closed')
RuntimeError: Session is closed
```

It looks like aiohttp closes the session before logout is completed?!

I'm not sure how to debug that any further?
What am I missing?

Comment: I forgot, MyServerSession has `def close(self): if not self.need_login: self.loop.run_until_complete(self.logout())`.

Answer (score 0):

Now answering my own question.

In the following tests asnyc context managers are shown, first 2 nested async with blocks and then one using closing() from contextlib.

```
class asy_context1:
    def __aenter__(self):
        print("c1: enter")
        return asyncio.sleep(0.3)
    def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        print("c1: exit")
        return asyncio.sleep(0.3)

class asy_context2:
    def __aenter__(self):
        print("c2: enter")
        return asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        print("c2: exit")
        return asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def test2async_withs():
    async with asy_context1() as a1:
        async with asy_context2() as a2:
            pass
            # raise RuntimeError("unexpected")  # also works

from contextlib import closing

class asy_context3:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
    async def logout(self):
        print("logging out")
    def close(self):
        print("c3:close")
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.logout())

async def test_mixed_withs(loop):
    async with asy_context1() as a1:
        with closing(asy_context3(loop)) as a3:
            pass
            # raise RuntimeError("unexpected")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test2async_withs())
loop.run_until_complete(test_mixed_withs(loop))
loop.close()
```

The output of this is:

```
c1: enter
c2: enter
c2: exit
c1: exit
c1: enter
c3:close
c1: exit
logging out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_exceptions.py", line 143, in <module>
    test_case2()
  File "test_exceptions.py", line 140, in test_case2
    loop.run_until_complete(test_mixed_withs(loop))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 385, in run_until_complete
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.
```

While the nested async context manager work as expected, the usage of closing() does not.

The point seems to be, that the timing of of the new loop start in asy_context3.close() is just not defined. close() is called in sequence, but the loop.run_until_complete() in close() seems to be scheduled after asy_context1.__ aexit __().

contextlib.closing() obviously is not meant to be used in asyncio context.